# RoR Uninitialized Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have two classes Student and Guardian. A third class Stud_guard governs the relationship between Student and Guardian classes. A snapshot of the classes is given below:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one    :stud_guards, :foreign_key => 'student_id', :dependent=>:destroy
end

class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :stud_guards, :dependent=>:destroy
end

class StudGuard < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student_id, :class_name => 'Student'
    belongs_to :guardian_id, :class_name => 'Guardian'
end
```

In the code, if I execute @guardian.stud_guards (where @guardian contains a valid guardian item), I'm able to obtain an array of stud_guard entries. However, if I execute @student.stud_guards (where @student has a valid student item), I get an ***"uninitialized constant Student::StudGuards"*** error. I cant seem to understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: have you tried removing `foreign_key`?

Comment: ok. you are doing `@student.stud_guards` while you have `has_one` relation. so try `@student.stud_guard`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#has_one` should take the model name as *singular* form.

```
has_one  :stud_guard
```

If you write `has_one  :stud_guards`, then it is looking for a model named as `StudGuards`, which doesn't exist and you got the error. With `#has_one`, Rails wouldn't apply [`#singularize`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/singularize) method on the association name , `stud_guards`, but [`#camelcase`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/String/camelcase).

```
'stud_guards'.camelcase # => "StudGuards" 
'stud_guard'.camelcase # => "StudGuard"
```

If you notice *"uninitialized constant Student::StudGuards"*, it is clear that Rails search for the model `StudGuards`, which it deduced as I said from `:stud_guards`. But If you write `stud_guard`, it would get `StudGuard`, which you have defined.

Hope it clears now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one    :stud_guard, :foreign_key => 'student_id', :dependent=>:destroy
end

class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :stud_guards, :dependent=>:destroy
end

class StudGuard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student_id, :class_name => 'Student'
  belongs_to :guardian_id, :class_name => 'Guardian'
end
```

And use it like:

```
@student.stud_guard
```